# c# cant get a random to execute a statement

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to make a simple rpg game where a computer chooses a random statements (image.width -=20 and image.width -=10 etc.)

i do not know how to this, i made a dictionary and an array but you can only display ints and strings etc in there and not statements. can anyone help me,

what i am trying to do is= when i press a button a *random* should choose between  statements and one should be executed , 
 how can i do this?

what i tried = **dictionary** and **array**

Comment: Share the related code block?

Comment: If its a finite number of statements you could make an Enum containing names of statements and use a switch to call a function containing said statement

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I am following what you want. Would choosing a random integer between 0 and the number of statements you have minus 1 and then putting those statements into a switch work for you? So for `case 0` do your first statement, `case 2` your second etc.

Comment: there is no code to show only a dictionary and an  array but that is not usefull for you to use

Comment: @John , i want to make a button, when clicked it should start a random, and in that random it must randomly choose between 3 methods, in my case it should change the width of an hp-bar image, but i have no idea how to do this

Comment: Could you add some Pseudo code of the wanted behaviour or a better explanation of the wanted behaviour. Now it is vague what you want to achieve. What do the statements do, is -20 and -10 fixed numbers? 

For example you could add an Action or an Func<T> to your dictionary. But this does not seem a clean solution

Comment: @svenQ i added  an action and it worked,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array of Actions. Here I use lambda expressions to introduce the Statements. Then you choose a random index for the array and execute the lambda expression behind the index.

```
Action[] yourStatements = new Action[]
 {
  () => image.width -= 20,
  () => image.width -= 10
  // you can add more actions
 };

Random random = new Random();
yourStatements[random.Next(yourStatements.Length)].Invoke();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i appreciate your answer it worked for me and i know understand how to do this the next time too.